# How do I store data from a file in a function in an array and then print that array?

Tags: c, arrays, file-management, read-write

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 12

int readInventory(char filename[], int item[], float price[]);


int main(void)
{
    int item[MAX_SIZE], i;
    float price[MAX_SIZE];
    char filename[MAX_SIZE];
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++ )
    {
      readInventory(filename, &item[i], &price[i]);
      printf("\n%d %.2f\n", item[i], price[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}


int readInventory(char filename[], int item[], float price[])
{

    FILE *inventory;
    int i;

    inventory = fopen("inventory.dat", "r");


    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++ )
    {
      fscanf(inventory,"%d%f", &item[i], &price[i]);         
      return 1;
    }
    fclose(inventory);
    return 0;
}
```

which prints out:

> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00
>
> 1200 20.00

which are only the first 2 items in the file

how do I make my program show all 12 different items?

Comment: Remove the `return 1` from the function `for` loop.

Comment: Take a look at that loop where you read, and remember that `return` returns from the function *immediately*.

Comment: And decide where you want the loop - Either in the readInventory function or outside, but not in both places.

Comment: You need to check the returned result from fopen and fscanf.

Answer (score 0):

Including a return 1 statement in your code returns from the for loop immediately. Remove that and it should work.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 12

int readInventory(char filename[], int item[], float price[]);


int main(void)
{
    int item[MAX_SIZE], i;
    float price[MAX_SIZE];
    char filename[MAX_SIZE];
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++ )
    {
      readInventory(filename, &item[i], &price[i]);
      printf("\n%d %.2f\n", item[i], price[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}


int readInventory(char filename[], int item[], float price[])
{

    FILE *inventory;
    int i;

    inventory = fopen("inventory.dat", "r");


    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++ )
    {
      fscanf(inventory,"%d%f", &item[i], &price[i]);         
    }
    fclose(inventory);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need of readInventory() call in for loop, it will repeatedly without any use.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 12

int readInventory(char filename[], int item[], float price[]);

int main(void)
{
    int item[MAX_SIZE], i, err = 0;
    float price[MAX_SIZE];
    char filename[MAX_SIZE] = "data";

    if ((err = readInventory(filename, item, price)) != 0) {
        return err;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d: %d %.2f\n",i+1, item[i], price[i]);

    return 0;
}

int readInventory(char filename[], int item[], float price[])
{
    FILE *inventory = NULL;
    int i;

    if ((inventory = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s\n", filename);
        return (1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        fscanf(inventory, "%d%f", &item[i], &price[i]);

    fclose(inventory);
    return 0;
}
```

you can try this. see the difference in passing array, doing error checking for function calls. code indentation.

Comment: Thank you, this explained it! the only difference is i returned 1 if the function failed to open the file and did the error printf statement in main

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your code, it will work,
Remove readInventory() in for loop, Calling the function once can do the job.

For printing put a printf() in readInventory() for loop after fscanf and remove the return 1 statement from there.